# How to set the background image from the assets folder in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

I am trying to set background image of my angular website from the assets folder. Here is my code:

app.component.html

```
<div [style.background]="/assets/burn_calories.jpg"></div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="default.asp">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.asp">PLAN</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.asp">HISTORY</a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a href="about.asp">LOGIN</a></li>
  </ul>
```

The image is located in the assets folder

app.component.css

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  }

  li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  }

  li a {
    display: block;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  /* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
  li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
  }

  .active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
  }
```

I am assuming the background image has to be set at the app component level. I am getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Unexpected token
>   / at column 1 in [/assets/burn_calories.jpg] in
>   ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@0:25 ("]/assets/burn_calories.jpg">

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting a literal value using bracket notation, you need to set a literal value as if you were writing javascript - by using string notation.

```
<div [style.background]="'url(/assets/burn_calories.jpg)'"></div>
```

If you don't use string notation, you are telling Angular that it should call a function called url, passing in the argument /assets/burn_calories.jpg, which is not going to compile.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uk5k5q

Comment: It still doesn't work. I am not getting the background

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. You do need to use bracket notation in this case. You don't need to when setting input values on child components or directives, but clearly do when setting `style.` properties. I've updated my answer.